# 'args not defined' error from leastsq function

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares, args

I tried fitting a function to data from a matrix synthData in the form of arrays synthData[0,:], synthData[1,:], and the y-values synthData[2,:]. But the following snippet returns "name 'args' not defined"

```
guess = [16.200000, -0.700000, 5.900000, -0.200000]

def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    # fitter will understand that x[0] equiv. to synthData[:,0], etc.
    return a + b*x[0] + c*x[1] + d*x[0]*x[1]
scipy.optimize.leastsq(func,guess,args(synthData,synthData[2,:]))
```

I've fiddled with it and searched around in SO, but can't figure out what it's getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing an equals sign:

```
scipy.optimize.leastsq(func,guess,args=(synthData,synthData[2,:]))
```

Comment: D'oh. That was definitely part of the problem; thanks. Now it says 'func() takes exactly 5 arguments (3 given)'. I guess I just don't understand the args, if I have already stated other arguments within the function. And if I re-state them in args(), it says 'Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))', where N are data points and M are the number of parameters.

Comment: ... and the help says that args are 'extra arguments to the function,' but then it's not clear to me why just stating args=(synthData,synthData[2,:]) is insufficient.

Comment: Have you tried putting there explicitly `args=(sunthData[0], synthData[1], synthData[2], synthData[3])`. Now it looks like it only thinks you give it 2 parameters + the guessed x, hence it says that you have given the function only 3 arguments.